# How can I programmatically compose an email on Apple Watch?

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos

How can I open the email app to the compose screen, with the message body preloaded with specific text?

Here is an example of composing SMS on apple watch and it completely works, but I need to compose an email on my watch app.

```
let messageBody = "Hello World!"

let urlSafeBody = messageBody.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())

if let urlSafeBody = urlSafeBody, url = NSURL(string: "sms:&body=\(urlSafeBody)") {
    WKExtension.sharedExtension().openSystemURL(url)
}
```

Comment: No idea if it works on an Apple Watch, but can you use a [mailto URL](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MailLinks/MailLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH4-SW1) in the same way, with a body param?

Comment: I changed "sms:" to "email" and "mail" but it didn't work.

Comment: Why those and not mailto?

Comment: I changed it to mailto and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any way to do that I'm afraid.  On iOS you'd use [MFMailComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller),  but there is no equivalent on WatchOS.

What I've done in the past is [sent a message](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615687-sendmessage) to a companion iPhone app that then generates the email on behalf of the watch app.

Comment: I was able to compose SMS from watch app, but for email i don't know how to implement it.